# Haskell: unexpected "Not in scope" error for simple function

Tags: haskell

This is very ad-hoc example describes `Not in scope: isOne` error that I have:

```
ignoreFirstOnes :: [Int] -> [Int]
ignoreFirstOnes (1:xs) = dropWhile isOne xs
ignoreFirstOnes xs     = xs
  where isOne = (== 1)
```

Strange that `isOne` function was defined in `where`, however compiler keeps complaining. I can rewrite that using guards or even to `dropWhile (== 1)` but I would like to understand how to make work the current example.

Comment: This is part of the reason I prefer `case` for most functions: I often want to use a `where` clause definition in multiple branches, and equational style doesn’t allow it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Names defined in a `where` clause are only in scope over the branch that the `where` clause is attached to.

This version of your definition will compile, because I attached the `where` clause to the branch of `ignoreFirstOnes` that uses `isOne`.

```
ignoreFirstOnes :: [Int] -> [Int]
ignoreFirstOnes (1:xs) = dropWhile isOne xs
    where isOne = (== 1)
ignoreFirstOnes xs = xs
```

Though note that this definition is equivalent to `ignoreFirstOnes = dropWhile (==1)`, which I think is simpler.

Comment: Yes, I have already mentioned about `dropWhile (==1)` in question, meaning that this example is only to describe my concern. However, I have never known about this feature, so thank you.